# Why the Python scope seems to behave differently for list variable and string variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-languages

Say that I have the following Python code:

```
import sys

class DogStr:
    tricks = ''

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks = trick

class DogList:
    tricks = []

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)

# Dealing with DogStr
d = DogStr()
e = DogStr()
d.add_trick('trick d')
e.add_trick('trick e')
print(d.tricks)
print(e.tricks)

# Dealing with DogList
d = DogList()
e = DogList()
d.add_trick('trick d')
e.add_trick('trick e')
print(d.tricks)
print(e.tricks)
```

Running this code with Python 3.6.5, I get the following output:

```
trick d
trick e
['trick d', 'trick e']
['trick d', 'trick e']
```

The difference between DogStr and DogList is that I treat `tricks` as a string on former and as a list on the latter.

When dealing with DogStr, tricks is behaving as an instance variable. BUT with DogList tricks is behaving as a class variable.

I was expecting to see the same behaviour on both calls, i.e.: if the two last lines of the output are identical, so should be the first two.

So I wonder. What is the explanation for that?

Comment: They're not behaving differently. If you do `self.tricks = trick` with your list, you will see exactly the same behavior as with strings. The difference is that you're doing something different—you're mutating the list value, which you aren't doing with the string value (and, in fact, can't do, because strings are immutable).

Comment: Anyway, this is definitely a duplicate of a common question, but I'm looking for the best answer. Meanwhile, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333000/what-is-the-difference-between-assign-list-with-x-list-and-x-list) have some useful info, even if they aren't duplicates.

Comment: I'm inexperienced with Python. So I didn't know that this was a common question. I couldn't find an equivalent question but, thank you for pointing related questions.

Comment: Also see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923579/python-class-attribute) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721002/is-a-variable-the-name-the-value-or-the-memory-location?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I'm giving up the search for now; hopefully someone else finds the dup.

Comment: The rule is that you're supposed to search for dups before posting… but the automated dup finder is useless, and, as you can see, I'm having a hard time finding the dup for this one despite knowing the python tag here pretty well and having found it in the past, so… I'd hardly blame you for not being able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is not int the type of the object, but in what your code does to it.

There is a big difference between these two:

```
self.tricks = trick
```

and:

```
self.tricks.append(trick)
```

The first one `self.tricks = trick` assigns a value to attribute `tricks` of `self`.

The second one `self.tricks.append(trick)` retrieves `self.tricks` and calls a method on it (which here modifies its values).

---

The problem, in your case, is that there is no `tricks` defined on `self` instance, so `self.tricks.append` gets the `tricks` attribute of the class and modifies it, but `self.tricks = ...` creates a new attribute on `self` instead.

The fact that one of them is a string and the other is a list is not really relevant. It would be the same if both were lists.
*Note that they could not both be strings because strings are immutable and thus have no append method*

### How to fix it?

This is wrong:

```
def add_trick(self, trick):
    self.tricks = trick
```

If `tricks` is a class attribute, `add_trick` should be a class method:

```
@classmethod
def add_trick(cls, trick):
    cls.tricks = trick
```

If there are reasons for `add_trick` to be an instance method, then simply do this:

```
def add_trick(self, trick):
    DogStr.tricks = trick
```

Comment: The point of initialization, in relation to the scope, really got me confused. Thank you for clearing this up.